# How to retrieve links posted by third-party Facebook apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink

Hi i need to retreive all my links for an app. I have try with "me/feed?limit=9999&access_token=" but this string not get all my links. Only the lasts.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Feed endpoint try the Link endpoint:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/

That should get all the links posted by the authenticated user